# How to get the ID of a deleted row from a list in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to delete an element from an array that I am displaying as a list using a ForEach, but I also need to send a HTTP request to a Stripe API and I need to put the id of the element in the body of the request. Here is my code:

```
List {
    ForEach(stripeManager.paymentMethods) { card in
    
        HStack {
            Image(card.brand)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 35, height: 25)
                .padding(.trailing, 10)
            Text("•••• \(card.last4)")
                .font(.system(size: 18, weight: .regular, design: .rounded))
        
            Spacer()
        
            Text("\(String(card.expMonth))/\(String(card.expYear))")
                .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .regular, design: .rounded))
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
        }
        .padding(.vertical)

    }
    .onDelete(perform: self.delete)
}
.toolbar {
    EditButton()
}
```

Here is the delete function:

```
func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    
    stripeManager.paymentMethods.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    
    stripeManager.detachPaymentMethod(paymentMethodId: i need to add card.id here)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try something like this:

```
func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    for i in offsets.makeIterator() {
        let theCardId = stripeManager.paymentMethods[i].id
        stripeManager.detachPaymentMethod(paymentMethodId: theCardId)
    }
    stripeManager.paymentMethods.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
}
```